# Making a list of dict from a list of lists with the list[0] as keys and other lists as values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, arraylist, key, key-value

could you tell me how can I get a list of dicts from that with the a[0] as keys for each dict and a[1:] as values accordingly.

```
a = [['PORT', 'NAME', 'STATUS', 'VLAN', 'DUPLEX', 'SPEED', 'TYPE', 'FC_MODE'], ['Gi1/0/1', 'S1-P1-01 Cisco_Roo', 'connected', '248', 'a-full', 'a-1000', '10/100/1000BaseTX', ''], ['Gi1/0/2', '', 'notconnect', '121', 'auto', 'auto', '10/100/1000BaseTX', ''], ['Gi1/0/3', '', 'notconnect', '121', 'auto', 'auto', '10/100/1000BaseTX', '']]
```

I wanna get

[{'PORT' : 'Gi1/0/1',
'NAME' : 'S1-P1-01 Cisco_Roo',
.
.
.
},
{'PORT' : 'Gi1/0/2',
'NAME' : '',
.
.
.
}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is probably:

```
[dict(zip(a[0], x)) for x in a[1:]]
```

This walks through each element from 1 onwards, and combines it with the first element, converting to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
a = [
    ['PORT', 'NAME', 'STATUS', 'VLAN', 'DUPLEX', 'SPEED', 'TYPE', 'FC_MODE'], 
    ['Gi1/0/1', 'S1-P1-01 Cisco_Roo', 'connected', '248', 'a-full', 'a-1000', '10/100/1000BaseTX', ''],
    ['Gi1/0/2', '', 'notconnect', '121', 'auto', 'auto', '10/100/1000BaseTX', ''],
    ['Gi1/0/3', '', 'notconnect', '121', 'auto', 'auto', '10/100/1000BaseTX', '']
    ]

import pandas as pd 

pd.DataFrame(a[1:],columns=a[0]).to_dict(orient="records")
```

Creates this output.

```
[{'PORT': 'Gi1/0/1',
  'NAME': 'S1-P1-01 Cisco_Roo',
  'STATUS': 'connected',
  'VLAN': '248',
  'DUPLEX': 'a-full',
  'SPEED': 'a-1000',
  'TYPE': '10/100/1000BaseTX',
  'FC_MODE': ''},
 {'PORT': 'Gi1/0/2',
  'NAME': '',
  'STATUS': 'notconnect',
  'VLAN': '121',
  'DUPLEX': 'auto',
  'SPEED': 'auto',
  'TYPE': '10/100/1000BaseTX',
  'FC_MODE': ''},
 {'PORT': 'Gi1/0/3',
  'NAME': '',
  'STATUS': 'notconnect',
  'VLAN': '121',
  'DUPLEX': 'auto',
  'SPEED': 'auto',
  'TYPE': '10/100/1000BaseTX',
  'FC_MODE': ''}]
```